# WPF RoutedEvent (via EventManager.RegisterClassHandler)

Tags: wpf, routedevent

I'm trying to find a generic way to track "Modified" of any control (databind or not) in the current window (this is e.g. to enable or disable the Apply button in a typical Options window.)  In fact, I just need to hook up a few event handlers like ComboBox.SelectionChanged or TextBox.TextChanged. In WinForms I had to loop through all controls in the form and hook up those events one by one, and it worked. In WPF, I thought I could get it done with much less code like

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler( typeof(MyCtrl)
                                 , ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent
                                 , new RoutedEventHandler(OnChanged));
```

With this one line code, I would be able to wire up comobobox's selection changed event for all comboboxes in MyCtrl. However, the problem I ran into is that, if I see it correctly, this event is also fired when there is another control in the window that is not a combobox but also derived from "`Selector`". For example, I also have a datagrid on the same window (actually there is no combobox column in the datagrid), this event is also fired when I select a different row.

So, it appears that the above line of code hooks up the SelectionChanged event for all controls derived from `Selector` base, not just combobox.

Is this right? How can I just hook up the SelectionChanged event for all comboboxes?

EDIT with more examples: On the same control, I have a comboxbox and a button and I want to track Button.Click and ComboBox.SelectionChanged event as follows

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler( typeof(MyCtrl)
                                 , ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent
                                 , new RoutedEventHandler(OnChanged));
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler( typeof(MyCtrl)
                                 , Button.ClickEvent
                                 , new RoutedEventHandler(OnChanged));
```

The problem is that I get Button.Click event right after I clicked the ComboBox dropdown button. How can I prevent this?

Here is some extra info for this event:

```
?e.OriginalSource
{System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton Content: 
            IsChecked:True}
    base {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase}: 
            {System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton Content: IsChecked:True}
    IsChecked: true
    IsThreeState: false
?e.RoutedEvent
{ButtonBase.Click}
    HandlerType: {Name = "RoutedEventHandler" 
                  FullName = "System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler"}
    Name: "Click"
    OwnerType: {Name = "ButtonBase" 
                FullName = "System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase"}
    RoutingStrategy: Bubble
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can prevent this because those controls reuse the same events, which is normally a good thing. You could try to filter based on the sender and ignore the calls that come from controls that you are not interested in.